# Allocating values into previous date buckets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Okay, this is a little convoluted (to me at least) which is why I'm asking for help here.

I have a table of Apples that are bought on the scheduled months. I then need to deliver them out so I'll need to know how much delivery capacity I need.

From the first table, on the 1st of January I have 100 apples in storage, 100 in reserve, due to buy 150 apples in by the end of Jan-18, 250 apples by the end of Feb-18 so on and so forth.

I then need to tag these apples to the delivery schedule which is listed on the second table. Everything in Storage and Reserves is assumed to be delivered in the closest available delivery.

However, if come 1st of February I discovered that I only managed to deliver 100 out of 150 apples, the remaining 50 in Jan-18 will have to be scheduled to the closest delivery which would be Feb-18

Similarly, when my buying schedule exceeds my delivery schedule, the exceeded amounts will be counted as part of the closest available delivery. For example, my last delivery is scheduled only to end of August but my purchase schedule extends to October. So my August delivery will be the sum of Aug-18, Sep-18 and Oct-18

Purchase Schedule (Input):

```
      |A              |B        |C        |D        |
    1 |Desc/Input Date|30-Jan-18|31-Jan-18|01-Feb-18|
    2 |Storage        |100      |50       |50       |
    3 |Reserve        |100      |50       |50       |
    4 |Jan-18         |150      |50       |50       |
    5 |Feb-18         |250      |250      |250      |
    6 |Mar-18         |150      |150      |150      |
    7 |Apr-18         |100      |100      |100      |
    8 |May-18         |25       |0        |0        |
    9 |Jun-18         |50       |50       |50       |
    10|Jul-18         |100      |100      |100      |
    11|Aug-18         |200      |200      |200      |
    12|Sep-18         |200      |200      |200      |
    13|Oct-18         |         |50       |50       |
```

Delivery Schedule (Ideal Output):

```
     |A   |B            |C        |D        |E        |
    1|Desc|Delivery Date|30-Jan-18|31-Jan-18|01-Feb-18|
    2|Jan |31-Jan-18    |350      |0        |0        |
    3|Feb |28-Feb-18    |250      |400      |400      |
    4|Mar |31-Mar-18    |150      |150      |150      |
    5|Apr |30-Apr-18    |100      |100      |100      |
    6|Jul |31-Jul-18    |175      |150      |150      |
    7|Aug |31-Aug-18    |400      |450      |450      |
```

My Conversion Table:

```
      |A              |B        |C        |D        |
    1 |Desc/Input Date|30-Jan-18|31-Jan-18|01-Feb-18|
    2 |Storage        |Jan      |Feb      |Feb      |
    3 |Reserve        |Jan      |Feb      |Feb      |
    4 |Jan-18         |Jan      |Feb      |Feb      |
    5 |Feb-18         |Feb      |Feb      |Feb      |
    6 |Mar-18         |Mar      |Mar      |Mar      |
    7 |Apr-18         |Apr      |Apr      |Apr      |
    8 |May-18         |Jul      |Jul      |Jul      |
    9 |Jun-18         |Jul      |Jul      |Jul      |
    10|Jul-18         |Jul      |Jul      |Jul      |
    11|Aug-18         |Aug      |Aug      |Aug      |
    12|Sep-18         |0        |0        |0        |
    13|Oct-18         |0        |0        |0        |
```

So far what I've done is create a separate Conversion Table that allocates the schedule. It is basically a `VLookUp` after comparing the Input Dates, Delivery Dates and Purchase Months.

Then a `IfError` that refer to previous cell. However, if I used `IfError` to refer to previous cell, then I could not then use it for the later scheduled deliveries. I was wondering if there's a better way of going about this?

My Formula for Conversion Table `Range("B2")`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B$1>INDEX(DeliverySchedule!$B:$B,MATCH(TEXT($A2,"Mmm"),DeliverySchedule!$A:$A,0)),B3,TEXT($A2,"Mmm")),B3)
```

My Formula for Delivery Schedule `Range("B2")`:

```
=SUMIF(ConversionTable!B:B,$A2,PurchaseSchedule!B:B)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your formulas.

Comment: @girlvsdata Sorry about that. Done!

Comment: "if come 1st of February (Second Column) I discovered that I only managed to deliver 100 out of 150 apples" <-- I can't see the 100 value @ 1st Feb in your table.. may I know where it is..?

Comment: @p._phidot_ my apols, That sentence was made with another example in mind but just treat it as a generalized example I guess.